# Gmail auto-reply each weekend?

Tags: gmail

I cannot find a feature in Gmail which will let me set an auto-reply message sent **each weekend** automatically?!

So any person who send an email to me during Sat or Sun will get auto-reply that I will reply them on Monday.

Does such thing exist in Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no you can't.  You can use the 'automatic vacation' responder found on the first page of settings within GMail to set a specific date, however you're going to have to do that at the end of each week.

More here - http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25922

Comment: So no add-on for this? Even in experimental section?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.